# How to change uuid wmic csproduct get uuid

Tags: wmic

I want to change my system uuid by command i am getting it by typing wmic csproduct get uuid but unable to edit it. my id is FFFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFF

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [2-minute tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Moreover, open [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read at least _What topics can I ask about here_?

Answer (score 4):

Read [Win32_ComputerSystemProduct class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394105(v=vs.85).aspx) MSDN article:

> The `Win32_ComputerSystemProduct` WMI class represents a product. This
>   includes software and hardware used on this computer system.
>
> The following syntax is simplified from Managed Object Format (`MOF`)
>   code and includes all of the inherited properties. Properties are
>   listed in alphabetic order, not `MOF` order.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> [Dynamic, Provider("CIMWin32"), UUID("{FAF76B96-798C-11D2-AAD1-006008C78BC7}"), AMENDMENT]
> class Win32_ComputerSystemProduct : CIM_Product
> {
>   string Caption;
>   string Description;
>   string IdentifyingNumber;
>   string Name;
>   string SKUNumber;
>   string UUID;
>   string Vendor;
>   string Version;
> };
> ```

All properties (listed above) are **read-only**, for instance

> **UUID**
>
> Data type: **string** 
>  Access type: Read-only 
>  Qualifiers:
>   [MappingStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393650(v=vs.85).aspx) ("SMBIOS|Type 1|UUID")
>
> Universally unique identifier (UUID) for this product. A UUID is a
>   128-bit identifier that is guaranteed to be different from other
>   generated UUIDs. If a UUID is not available, a UUID of all zeros is
>   used.
>
> This value comes from the **UUID** member of the **System
>   Information** structure in the SMBIOS information.

**Conclusion**: you cannot change system `UUID` via any `WMI` method. Ask Google and SuperUser for another way (if some exists at all).

> A `UUID` is an identifier that is designed to be unique across both
>   time and space. It requires no central registration process. The
>   `UUID` is 128 bits long. Its format is described in [RFC 4122: A
>   Universally Unique IDentifier (UUID) URN Namespace](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt).